# How did Einstein develop his harmonic oscillator model for solids if there was no solution for the quantum harmonic oscillator yet?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, harmonic-oscillator, history

The Einstein model for solids (at least in the modern presentation) requires knowing that a quantum harmonic oscillator has energy levels:

$$E_n =\hbar \omega (n+1/2) $$

This result can be obtained from the Schrödinger equation imposing a harmonic oscillator potential. Knowing this, one writes down the partition function and works from there. However, the Schrödinger equation was developed in 1925, while Einstein's paper dates from 1907. How could Einstein develop this model before the energy states of a quantum harmonic oscillator were known?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very interesing question and personally, the answer really surprised me. I have found the paper where Einstein proposes the model of a solid and derives its thermodynamic properties. It turns out that the aim of the paper was to actually show that the planck law along with $E = h\nu$ was a general law of nature. I guess he just got lucky that the quantum SHO has a similar energy spectrum to light. The original paper is in german, therefore I cannot add more insightful comments and am restricted to what Wikipedia is telling me. To learn more, here are some useful links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_scientific_publications_by_Albert_Einstein

[http://myweb.rz.uni-augsburg.de/~eckern/adp/history/einstein-papers/1907_22_800.pdf](http://myweb.rz.uni-augsburg.de/%7Eeckern/adp/history/einstein-papers/1907_22_800.pdf)

Comment: From skimming the formulas in the paper, it seems like he simply assumed $E=h\nu$, trying to show it was a general principle, as you say. It makes sense that he is neglecting the zero point energy term, then.

Comment: Yeah the zero point energy just cancels and doesn’t affect the overall result.

Comment: this may illuminate that oscillator solutions exist in classical mechanics https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Quantum_Mechanics/06._One_Dimensional_Harmonic_Oscillator/Harmonic_Oscillator

Comment: @annav Well yes, but the solution is not a set of quantized energy levels, the classical harmonic oscillator can have an arbitrary energy.

Comment: There are distinct frequencies in the classical oscilator, one did not need quantum mechanics for vibrations of violin strings?

Comment: A violin string is not the same as a simple harmonic oscillator though.